# Como mudar de página ao acabar uma animação?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria que quando acabasse essa animação que potei no código, apágina da animação fosse rederecionado pra outra página nesse cadao, para o "index.php", ou seja, aparece essa animação a dar as boas vindas à pessoa, e mal que acaba a animação, redireciona para o index.php.

Nota: a pagina da animação chama-se inicio.php , n se confunda!

```js
//CSS Text Animation



// JQUERY
$(function() {

 
 // Will wait for everything on the page to load.
 $(window).bind('load', function() {
  $('.overlay, .body').addClass('loaded');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('.overlay').css({'display':'none'})
        }, 10000);
        
    });
    
 // Will remove overlay after 1min for users cannnot load properly.
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('.overlay, .body').addClass('loaded');
 }, 60000);
    
   
});


function xavieumamor_ps_de_gato_eheh() 

(function xavieumamor_ps_de_gato_eheh() {("setTimeout:location.replace('index.php')"); }, 4500);{

   
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400');
body {
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:100;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.nav>li>a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropping-texts {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

.dropping-texts > div {
  font-size:0px;
  opacity:0;
  margin-left:-30px;
  position:absolute;
  font-weight:300;   
  box-shadow: 0px 60px 25px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(1) {
  animation: roll 5s linear infinite 0s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: roll 5s linear infinite 1s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(3) {
  animation: roll 5s linear infinite 2s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(4) {
  animation: roll2 5s linear infinite 3s;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  3% {
    opacity:1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
  }
  20% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  27% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0.5;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:100px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}

@keyframes roll2 {
  0% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  3% {
    opacity:1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
  }
  30% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  37% {
    font-size:1500px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-1000px;
    margin-top:-800px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {background: #ff0075;}
  3% {background: #0094ff;}
  20% {background: #0094ff;}
  23% {background: #b200ff;}
  40% {background: #b200ff;}
  43% {background: #8BC34A;}
  60% {background: #8BC34A;}
  63% {background: #F44336;}
  80% {background: #F44336;}
  83% {background: #F44336;}
  100% {background: #F44336;}
}



/*CSS DO LOAD*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab:400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,500,700');
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 outline-width: 0;
}
.body {
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 &.loaded {
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
}
.centre {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.overlay {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: #1c1c1c;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 100000;
 transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1);
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1);
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 &.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 p {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
 }
}
.loader {
 background: transparent;
 width: 84px;
 height: 84px;
 border-top: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-left: 4px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 1s ease infinite;
}
.Skip {
 background: transparent;
 margin-top: 45px;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 padding: 15px 35px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
 font-weight: bold;
 opacity: 0.4;
 &:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Carregando..</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/load.css">

  
</head>

<body onload="xavieumamor_ps_de_gato_eheh()">


<div class="overlay">
    <div class="dropping-texts">
                <div>Seja </div>
                    <div>Bem Vindo</div>
                    <div>à Queue Music</div>
                    <div>APROVEITE!</div>
                </div>
    </div>
  
  
</div>
  
  

      <!-- Loading -->
      <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mas a animação esta funcionando, apenas não está conseguindo mudar a url após seu término?

Comment: Sim! A animação está a funcionar mas quando acaba não está a mudar para outra página, neste caso para o meu index.
Basicamente é uma pequena animação de boas vindas ao site.

Answer (score 0):

Cara absolutamente nada que tem ali no seu **JS** é necessário, a animação é toda feita com **CSS**, então basta esperar a animação acabar o seu tempo e carregar outra **URL**:

```js
$(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      location.href = "inicio.php"     // chama outro arquivo
  },5000) 
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400');
body {
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:100;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.nav>li>a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropping-texts {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

.dropping-texts > div {
  font-size:0px;
  opacity:0;
  margin-left:-30px;
  position:absolute;
  font-weight:300;   
  box-shadow: 0px 60px 25px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(1) {
  animation: roll 5s linear 0s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: roll 5s linear 1s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(3) {
  animation: roll 5s linear 2s;
}
.dropping-texts > div:nth-child(4) {
  animation: roll2 5s linear 3s;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  3% {
    opacity:1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
  }
  20% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  27% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0.5;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:100px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}

@keyframes roll2 {
  0% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  3% {
    opacity:1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
  }
  30% {
    font-size:inherit;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  37% {
    font-size:1500px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-1000px;
    margin-top:-800px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size:0px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {background: #ff0075;}
  3% {background: #0094ff;}
  20% {background: #0094ff;}
  23% {background: #b200ff;}
  40% {background: #b200ff;}
  43% {background: #8BC34A;}
  60% {background: #8BC34A;}
  63% {background: #F44336;}
  80% {background: #F44336;}
  83% {background: #F44336;}
  100% {background: #F44336;}
}



/*CSS DO LOAD*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab:400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,500,700');
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 outline-width: 0;
}
.body {
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 &.loaded {
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
}
.centre {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.overlay {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: #1c1c1c;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 100000;
 transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1);
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1);
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 &.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 p {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
 }
}
.loader {
 background: transparent;
 width: 84px;
 height: 84px;
 border-top: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-right: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 border-left: 4px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 1s ease infinite;
}
.Skip {
 background: transparent;
 margin-top: 45px;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 padding: 15px 35px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
 font-weight: bold;
 opacity: 0.4;
 &:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay">
    <div class="dropping-texts">
         <div>Seja</div>
         <div>Bem Vindo</div>
         <div>à Queue Music</div>
         <div>APROVEITE!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E como faço isso?

Eu sei que é tudo em css, o js está sim a fazer algo, tem um botão aí de "Avançar", eu acho que cheguei a meter esse botao de Avançar a tranparente, que ao carregar vai pra outra pagina, mas eu queria isso ao acabar a animação, so que na o consigo fazer

Comment: André, não precisa de botão para isto, é só fazer do jeito que coloquei na resposta que vai funcionar.